# Check/change folder permission in shell script

Tags: shell-script, permissions

I am writing a script that downloads packages to a specific folder.

However, I want to make it possible for all users to download packages to that folder and use any packages installed there. How do I do that?

I want to check/change the permission for the `/usr/local/src` folder. I don't know how I've to use the if/else statement properly. In text it'll look like (I guess): `if stat/permission of src folder isn't 777 then chmod to 777`

Comment: Welcome to U&L, Hudhud!  Why exactly do you need everything in each src folder to have readable, writable, and executable permissions for every user?  Also feel free the peruse [Advanced Bash Scripting](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), [Bash Hackers](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/), and Google for information on how to write code in Bash.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I missed something, I want the folder /usr/local/src to have the permission 777 :)

Comment: So you want like a script that will periodically kick-off and check the permissions of `/usr/local/src` and make sure that everybody can read, write, and execute inside of that directory?

Comment: yes, exactly :)

Comment: What you'll want to look into is writing a cronjob that will run the script in question.  How often/periodically do you need/want that script to check on `/usr/local/src`'s permissions?

Comment: Why bother checking the current permissions. Just chmod it to 777. The real question is why you think you need it to be 777 in the first place. Why is that? You should consider 1777 at least.

Comment: @AlexejMagura I want it to check when the script is ran; so every time :).

Comment: @Unbeliever What if the script is ran on different computers, and why try to change the current permissions if they are already set to 777 (or 1777) before the running ? :)

Comment: @Unbeliever the sticky bit might be a good idea, but I don't know if Hudhud would want/need that.

Comment: @Hudhud, well, I meant more like when do you want the `chmod` script to be run, like how often?  Like every 5 minutes or once an hour, or once a week, what?

Comment: @Hudhud, you can use [Crontab Guru](http://crontab.guru/) to help you write a cronjob to run your `chmod` script.

Comment: ahh in that way.. I only want it to run only once :)

Comment: @Hudhud then why not just run the command `chmod 777 -R /usr/local/src` as root?  If you don't need it to run more than once, then just do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stat -c "%a" /usr/local/src` to get the full permissions. But you should consider 1777 instead of 777.

So something like

```
if [ "$(stat -c '%a' /usr/local/src)" == "777" ]
then
  # something
else
  # something else
fi
```

In answer to your other question, if the permissions are already 777 then there will be no effect.

EDIT: corrected typos. @Alexej Magura why would I use double brackets? As far as I'm aware that would turn it into an arithmetic expression ..

Comment: Why would you recommend that? and is there a way to say like: if the permissions aren't 777 (or 1777) then set to 777 (1777)?

Comment: Didn't read your edited version, but why do you recommend 1777?

Comment: 1777 means that other users a cannot delete user b's files and vice versa, where as 777 is more open

Comment: Please use double brackets, single brackets are only really necessary when you're running `dash` or `/bin/sh` and they support less advanced syntax.

Comment: Dear, when I do it this way it keeps thinking that the permissions aren't 777 even though they're. I've tried to check manually with stat it says 0777

Comment: Every time I run the script it tries to change the permissions

Comment: I use sudo chmod 777 -R /path/to/folder

Comment: Arg sorry ... the %s should be %a (typo). Corrected in the answer.